# Subscribe / import multiple ICS files into 1

Tags: calendar, icalendar

Does anyone know of a way to use something like Google Calendar to subscribe to multiple ICS calendar feeds so that I can create a new calendar with the ability to grab it's ICS feed so that all the events in Calendar A and Calendar B (as supplied via ICS feeds into the new Google Calendar) will appear together?

I need the new calendar to poll the feeding ICS files and not do a hard single import function.

E.g. I want a way of creating a new MASTER calendar which is feed by multiple existing ones via ICS feeds.

Comment: Was this ever solved? Looking for the same thing.

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://medium.com/teamup/how-to-consolidate-multiple-calendar-feeds-into-a-single-view-145d598235fc

Answer (score -1):

I managed to add multiple `ICSs` by following this method:

1. I sent an email to my gmail account and included in it a bunch of ICS files as attachments.
2. I opened the email inside gmail and hit an option of adding to calendar.

All done!

Comment: Gmail doesn't show option of adding to calendar if there are multiple ICS files